# Beginner JavaScript: Working with JSON and Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON returned to the browser like this "product":

```
{ "Title": "School Bag", "Image": "/images/school-bag.jpg" }
```

I want this data to be a "Product" object so I can use prototype methods like a `toHTMLImage()` that returns a HTML image representation of the product:

```
function Product() { }
Product.prototype.toHTMLImage = function() { //Returns something like <img src="<Image>" alt="<Title>" /> }
```

How do I convert my JSON results into a `Product` object so that I can use `toHTMLImage`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple, if I got it,

```
var json = { "Title": "School Bag", "Image": "/images/school-bag.jpg" }
function Product(json) {
    this.img = document.createElement('img');
    this.img.alt = json.Title;
    this.img.src = json.Image;

    this.toHTMLImage = function() {
        return this.img;
    }
}

var obj = new Product(json); // this is your object =D
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this page will be usefull : [http://www.json.org/js.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20161104150452/http://www.json.org:80/js.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
var stuff = { "Title": "School Bag", "Image": "/images/school-bag.jpg" }
var newstuff = new Product();
for(i in stuff) newstuff.i = stuff[i];
```

Not sure if this will work, but give it a shot:

```
var stuff = { "Title": "School Bag", "Image": "/images/school-bag.jpg" }
stuff.prototype = Product;
```

Comment: Try: stuff.__proto__ = Product.prototype;

Answer (score 0):

For converting JSON to an object you can use
`window.JSON.parse(jsonText)` in Mozilla (check Chrome and Opera, I don't know how it works there.)

In Internet Explorer you can use `(new Function("return " + jsonText))()`,
but you should check the JSON for non-valid symbols, google it.