# jQuery Each Multidimensional JSON Array

Tags: json, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem which I can't solve for trying for 3 days now. I have an JSON array:

```
var geojson = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              5.140439,
              51.686608
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          },
          "properties": {
            "title": "TEST1",
            "rentals": true,
            "tackleshop": false,
            "fuel": false,
            "marker-color": "#1087bf",
            "marker-size": "large",
            "marker-symbol": "harbor"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              5.134060,
              51.686890
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          },
          "properties": {
            "title": "TEST2",
            "rentals": true,
            "tackleshop": false,
            "fuel": true,
            "marker-color": "#1087bf",
            "marker-size": "large",
            "marker-symbol": "harbor"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              5.133729,
              51.681425
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          },
          "properties": {
            "title": "TEST3",
            "rentals": false,
            "tackleshop": true,
            "fuel": true,
            "marker-color": "#1087bf",
            "marker-size": "large",
            "marker-symbol": "harbor"
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

**What I have been tested now:**

```
$.each(geojson, function() {
            $.each(this, function(key, value) {
              $.each(this, function(value, featuress) {
              console.log(featuress.properties.title);

              });
            });
        });
```

**The result I want:**
I want a $.each which goes through this json array where I am able to display the variable for as example: "title" for each feature.

Who can help me out? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looped over a JSON object for 2 times, I removed the outer `foreach` loops. You can only iterate over a list - `features` in this case. See the snippet:

```js
var geojson = {  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               5.140439,
               51.686608
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "properties":{  
            "title":"TEST1",
            "rentals":true,
            "tackleshop":false,
            "fuel":false,
            "marker-color":"#1087bf",
            "marker-size":"large",
            "marker-symbol":"harbor"
         }
      }
   ]
}

$.each(geojson.features, function(i, feature) {
  console.log(feature.properties.title);
});

You looped over an object
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For further reading:

- [Beginner JavaScript: Working with JSON and Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866482/beginner-javascript-working-with-json-and-objects-in-javascript)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Answer (score 1):

As your code, `geojson` is a json object, it's not a json array.

Example for a json array is `[{"name":"item 1"},{"name": "item2} ]`.

To go throught list features and display its property, you could
try this:

```
$.each(geojson.features, function(index, feature) {
    console.log(feature.properties.title);
});
```